# How do I get or produce the Unicode needed in Tesseract box file?

Tags: linux, unicode, ocr, tesseract

In tesseract's google documentation here https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3  here, there is a instruction that I have to get Unicode for the generated characters in my box files.It looks like this

s 734 494 751 519 0

p 753 486 776 518 0

r 779 494 796 518 0

i 799 494 810 527 0

n 814 494 837 518 0

g 839 485 862 518 0

t 865 492 878 521 0

u 101 453 122 484 0

b 126 453 146 486 0

e 149 452 168 477 0

r 172 453 187 476 0

d 211 451 232 484 0

e 236 451 255 475 0

n 259 452 281 475 0

Now, my question is where or how I get this? I am developing an OCR for Bangla language.

Comment: I want to know how do I get the codes, something like 288 265 272, what are these? Why do I need three number for one character?

Answer (score 0):

The box file is a UTF-8 encoded text file. You can use a Unicode-compatible text editor, or a [box file editor](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/AddOns), to open and edit the characters with your favorite Bangla input method.

Comment: Do you mean I need to replace the a,b,c,d with the characters of Bengali?

Comment: Yes, type replace the wrong characters with correct ones.